# HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, database, postgresql, api, python-requests

I am trying to transfer string to 'wound_base' column in a remote SQL database but I am getting an error:

> HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed.

The wound_base column has no data type assigned and I don't have authority to modify the columns' data types. Does anyone know a work around this problem? Would be very Grateful. Thank you.

```
import requests

payload = {
  "status": "PROGRESS",
  "wound_base":"1;4"
}
headers = {}

try:
    
    response = requests.post(exam_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print("Successfully update examination")
```

Comment: Databases don't generally accept http requests; they have their own protocols, and their own python libraries

Comment: Check with your API documentation for the correct request method. 405 means that the URL you are using is not accepting `POST` method. The method could be `PUT` if you are using a REST API.

Comment: @JiříBaum I can transfer the data to rest of the columns using http requests except this particular : 'wound_base' column which has no data type assigned.

Comment: @Ananth I tried using PUT but I get the same error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh PgAdmin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "column has no data type assigned" is not a thing in PostgreSQL?